# Isothermal process and work done

Tags: thermodynamics, work

When work is done on a piston to **compress** the air **quasi-statically** but an amount of **heat** equal to the **work done on** the air is also **removed** from air, how is the work done **isothermal** in this situation? Please explain.

Comment: Is there a question here???

Comment: @ChetMiller sorry , i forgot to edit the question

Comment: The surroundings are *slightly* higher in temperature than the gas.

Comment: @ChetMiller , please tell me about the process , im not able to understand

Comment: This is in evert Thermo textbook.  What book are you using?

Comment: @Chet Miller I'm  using  **sontag and brokerage**

Comment: Get yourself a better book like Moran et al.

Comment: @Chet Miller OK  I will , Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an ideal gas, internal energy is only a function of temperature:
$$U = c_v T.$$
Furthermore, the change in internal energy is equal to the work done on the system plus the heat absorbed from the surroundings:
$$dU = \delta W + \delta Q.$$
Therefore, if $\delta Q = - \delta W$, the internal energy remains constant, which means the temperature remains constant as well.

Comment: Thank you i understand the solution

Answer (score 1):

If a process happens to take place without temperature change, then we call it **isothermal**.

If the temperature changes then it is because thermal energy has been added or removed. Thermal energy is a part of the so-called **internal energy**, $U$. So, if $U$ doesn't change, meaning if $\Delta U=0$, then the temperature doesn't change.

Now, look at the energy conservation law, the 1st law of thermodynamics:

$$\Delta U=Q+W.$$

Heat, $Q$, and work, $W$, are the to energy transfer methods that we know of. If $Q=W$, meaning if just as much heat is added/removed as work is being done so that they balance out, then $U$ doesn't change, $\Delta U=0$.

This is why you statement is true: "*heat removed is same as the work supplied*" means $Q=W$. There will be no temperature change when this is the case because the internal energy doesn't change - thus we call the process isothermal.

---

A quick note on the term: **quasi-statically**. When you compress the gas with the piston, then you are doing work on the gas since you are rearranging the particles, making them more compact. This is the work that is relevant; this is $W$. But if you do this very fast, then you are *also* adding extra energy to move about these particles. Meaning, you are also supplying energy as kinetic energy and subsequently also as thermal energy. This complicates the energy accounting a lot since we would need a larger $W$ than necessary and we might experience odd temperature fluctuations. Therefor, to keep the calculation simple and predictable, we'll assume that the piston is moved very slowly. So slowly that the system remains is close-to thermodynamic equilibrium all the time. This is termed: a quasi-static compression.

Comment: i am not sure but

Comment: Thank you but i am not sure   **Q = ∆U+W** , here  **∆U = Q-W** , heat is removed from the air so it is negative , and work is done on the system so its negative and thus **∆U=0**...plz tell me if it is correct

Comment: @johnmacmelon You might see different signs on these energy-transfer terms. For instance, if work done *on* the system (energy given to the system) is defined as positive, then you'd write: $$\Delta U = Q+W.$$ But if work done *by* the system (energy given to something else by the system) is defined as positive, then you'd write: $$\Delta U = Q-W.$$ If you are using the latter version, then no problem. Just be careful with the correct signs on values that you put in.

Comment: Thank you , it really helped